# Connecting to Cisco VPN drops wifi connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I use a work laptop (Lenevo Thinkpad T440p) and sometimes when I work from home, I try to connect via Cisco Anyconnect VPN.

## The problem

When I start my laptop and it gets automatically connected to my WiFi, everything works fine. The problem starts soon after I connect the VPN. The connection works for a while (2-3 minutes) and then suddenly, the WiFi at my home stops working - not for my laptop alone but for every device - phones and desktops. In order to solve this, I'm forced to either Reboot the device (via the router's administration page accessible via 192.168.0.1) or shut down my router for a few seconds and start it up again. And the cycle repeats.

After the Wifi drop, even if I disconnect my VPN the problem doesn't get solve and the connection remains unavailable for all the devices. It's only after the reboot/turning off of the router do things go back to normal.

However, if I don't use the Wifi and rely on the LAN cable instead, I see no problems with the VPN.

### Metadata

```
OS: Windows 7 64 bit
VPN Client: Cisco Anyconnect VPN v4.5
Device: Lenovo Thinkpad T440p
Router: TP Link WR740N
```

PS: I've absolutely no idea about networks so my terminology could be wrong but I've tried to be as accurate as possible.

Is there something that I can do to fix this at my end instead of having to contact the IT at work?

Comment: Will do and update the results. I just hope it doesn't mess with my current configuration and ends up not working with other devices too.

Comment: Most routers upgrading the firmware **doesn't** effect the settings saved in NV_RAM. If you are worried about it, make sure you back up your current router configuration to your computer or a USB stick. (The option is  usually under the admin tab inside the web gui) p.s, it's also good practice to save sequential backups when you make changes to your config. It allows you to quickly go back to a config you know works if you need to.

Comment: I have a similar problem on win10 and win11. No problem on mac and ios